# How to update AWS elasticsearch cluster setting via its rest API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using `AWS Elasticsearch` and I am trying to update its cluster setting but got an error:

```
$ curl -XPUT https://vpc-tf-security-search-roxodu3f3fdsfsdfuhu.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {"persistent" : { "indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec" : "50mb"}}'

{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

I wonder why I can't change that. Is it a limitation on AWS Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS restricts access to a number of APIs and settings.

supported API on AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_1